# How to call this function right?

Tags: python, list, function, call, phone-number

Hello guys I'm currently trying to build a phone_numbers generator with two methods. The first one is phone_numbers and should be called every time you need new generated number. You can get the numbers from next_phone_numbers. This function should also call phone_numbers if there are no numbers available. However I always get an error message when I call it. Here is my code:

```
 def phone_number(self):
        request = requests.get('https://www.bestrandoms.com/random-at-phone-number')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')

        self.phone_numbers = soup.select_one('#main > div > div.col-xs-12.col-sm-9.main > ul > textarea').text
        self.phone_numbers = self.phone_numbers.splitlines()
        for phone in range(len(self.phone_numbers)):
            self.phone_numbers[phone] = '+43' + self.phone_numbers[phone][1:].replace(' ', '')

        self.phone_numbers.extend(self.phone_numbers)
        return self.phone_numbers

    @property
    def next_phone_number(self):
        self.phone_index += 1
        if self.phone_index >= len(self.phone_numbers):
            self.phone_number()

        return self.phone_numbers[self.phone_index]
```

error-message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bmPy.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `phone_number()` function is not extending the `self.phone_numbers` list enough to cover the fact that the `self.phone_index` is out of range. Perhaps consider doing this to extend until it is large enough:

```
    @property
    def next_phone_number(self):
        self.phone_index += 1
        while self.phone_index >= len(self.phone_numbers):
            self.phone_number()

        return self.phone_numbers[self.phone_index]
```

Comment: No, that would be wrong and would build an endless loup. Thank you for your try.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `self.phone_numbers = soup.select_one(...)`, you're clobbering the old list of phone numbers you had in `self.phone_numbers` and replacing it with the data you've parsed from your web page. You later refine this into a new list, but it's still not doing what you want in terms of adding new numbers (I've not tried the code, I'd guess you always get the same amount of them from the web).

You should use a different variable name for the new data. That way you can `extend` the existing list with the new data without overwriting anything you already have:

```
def phone_number(self):
    request = requests.get('https://www.bestrandoms.com/random-at-phone-number')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')

    # these lines all use new local variables instead of clobbering self.phone_numbers
    new_data = soup.select_one('#main > div > div.col-xs-12.col-sm-9.main > ul > textarea').text
    new_numbers = new_data.splitlines()
    new_numbers_reformatted = ['+43' + number[1:].replace(' ', '') for number in new_numbers]

    # so now we can extend the list as desired
    self.phone_numbers.extend(new_numbers_reformatted)
    return self.phone_numbers
```

It's possible that you'll also need to change the initialization code in your class to make sure it initializes `self.phone_numbers` to an empty list, if it's not doing that already. The bad behavior of your method might have been covering up a bug if the list was not being created anywhere else.